# Проблема cfg GRUB

Tags: linux, config, grub

Linux 20.10 Пытаюсь войти в GRUB, изначально попытка не удалась. Проверил `/etc/default/grub`
Timeot выглядел так:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
```

Заменил на

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
```

Но не помогло.

Полный cfg выглядит так:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй изменить `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` на `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` или вообще удалить эту стоку.

Answer (score 1):

`update-grub2` не забыл? После изменения в /etc/ нужно применить их в /boot/